# HttpPost Method parse the wrong value (ASP.Net)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, http-post

I have a problem with my HttpPost Method or the way the browser sends the data.
When i type in a value, for example 50,47 (or 50.47. The seperator doesn't seems to be the problem), the value in the POST is 50.47. Up to this point everything seems fine. But the Post Method from the controller parse the wrong value and always get 5047.

I use following input:

```
<input asp-for="Preisnachlass" type="number" lang="de-de" step="0.01" min="0" class="form-control"/>
```

This is my POST Method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("BestellNr,BestellungsDatum,BestellStatus,BezahlungsDatum,VerwendungsDatum,Preisnachlass,GutscheinNr,KundenNr,ProduktNr")] Bestellung bestellung)
{
    if (id != bestellung.BestellNr)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Update(bestellung);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!BestellungExists(bestellung.BestellNr))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    ViewData["GutscheinNr"] = new SelectList(_context.Gutschein, "GutscheinNr", "GutscheinNr", bestellung.GutscheinNr);
    ViewData["KundenNr"] = new SelectList(_context.Kunde, "KundenNr", "KundenNr", bestellung.KundenNr);
    ViewData["ProduktNr"] = new SelectList(_context.Produkt, "ProduktNr", "ProduktNr", bestellung.ProduktNr);`

    return View(bestellung);
}
```

When i debug the whole thing this is what i get from the chrome dev tools:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/totOX.png (Sry for only post a link)

And this is what vs gets a the Post Method:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5i0B.png

I don't know how to debug it deeper to find the problem. Anyone an idea for this?

Comment: Make sure , your culture setting ..

Comment: I changed my culture settings mutiple times at different ways but nothings seems to work.

Comment: Your sending a value with a `.` (dot) as a the decial separator, therefore the culture on the server must be one that accepts that (e.g. en-US) - or you need to create a custom `ModelBinder`